# Could not load file or assembly or Assembly binding logging is turned OFF while running an application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-assembly, iis-10

I am trying to host an application in a system and I enabled the IIS for that system. Then I hosted the application and click on the browse option.But in Browser it is showing an error like,

```
Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Dashboard.v19.2.Web, Version=19.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Dashboard.v19.2.Web, Version=19.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'DevExpress.Dashboard.v19.2.Web, Version=19.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Is this issue because of any settings or Web.Config issues?

Please help me with this

Comment: Well, the mentioned DLL either should reside with your application DLLs, or it should be registered to the GAC (This is done by the devexpress application setup)

Comment: But how can I come out of this issue?

Comment: Either run the setup on the server machine or include the DLLs in the project and select copy to output so when you publish your application the related DLLs will be in place.

Comment: These same application files are working fine in one laptop IIS but not in another laptop IIS. why like that?

Comment: In your local machine, you probably have the Devexpress product installed. When you run the setup the installer, installs the DLLs into Global Assembly Cache (GAC), so when you reference a Devexpress DLL, it  (or any other its dependencies) doesn't have to be in the same folder with your application. (That's why it just works). In the server, you either copy `DevExpress.Dashboard.v19.2.Web.dll` and all dependencies into the application folder or you run the DevExpress v19.2 setup to install all DLLs into GAC.

Comment: https://docs.devexpress.com/AspNet/14777/redistribution-and-deployment/deployment-troubleshooting-guide?v=19.2#notload

Comment: What build + publishing model are you using to deploy the site? Those dll's should be included when you build + publish. Try publishing to a local folder, and then copy that to IIS (you have to edit your SQL connection strings first or hopefully you have some transforms setup to change then when you build + publish in release mode.

Comment: It seems that the DevExpress.Dashboard is missing in your deployment package.  You can use the [Assembly Deployment Tool](https://docs.devexpress.com/AssemblyDeploymentTool/17237/assembly-deployment-tool) to get a full list of DevExpress assemblies that your application requires.